# how to interpret multiple class id inside of single quotes

Tags: html, css, dom

I cannot find any answer on line officially what below means

```
<div class="item1 item2" id="id1">
```

First, what's with item1 item2 here in this context? How would you select them? What is it mean? It's any class with item1 OR item2 ? 
Secondly, how would you google this to find out ? Or what is the best resource for css + html learning?

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I got the answer.. it's just separate classes being applied to this div